# How to get count of objects from ManyToManyField in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a User and Event model,

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, default='')

class Event(models.Model):
    name    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user    = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name='event_player')
```

I want to get the number of users registered in events, I tried the following ways:

Try 1

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    players_count = serializers.IntegerField(
        source='user_set.count', 
        read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'name','players_count')
```

Try 2

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    players_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'name','players_count')

    def get_players_count(self, obj):
        return obj.user_set.all().count()
```

Try 3

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return {'id': instance.pk, 'players_count': instance.user__count}
        
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'name','players_count')
```

But none of them make a sense, how do I get the total count of nested ManyToMany Users. I'm new to DRF please help me to solve this.

Comment: You want to get the count of users for a specific event or all users that are registered?

Comment: I want to get count of users in a specific Event

Comment: what's wrong in try 2?

Comment: I'm getting an AttributeError at /api/v0/event/5/
'Event' object has no attribute 'user_set'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try 2 should work without `_set`
See [Django ManyToMany Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for more information

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    players_count = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ('id', 'name','players_count')

    def get_players_count(self, obj):
        return obj.user.all().count()
```